# laravel authentication :exact location of AuthController

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new to the laravel framework,and i setup the laravel basic authentication it simple and awesome.

I need a clarification in following things

1.when i list the all routes using route list command i can see the many routes including the functionalities for login and register ,but the routes not registerd in in `route.php` file ,how its worked?

2.I want to add some more fields in registration for that i am looking for this function `AuthController@register` ,but there is no function named `register` in it,so where it is actually located.??

EDIT

1.I need to find the login functions also,because I want to show custom error message to the user is(password not found,invalid email,account blocked )

2.want to change the route after logout

Comment: 1: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L367 2: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L53

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a proper php IDE that can do these lookups for you with a few clicks. I used phpstorm to finds these for you, but there are good free ones too. I hear netbeans is worth a try

Comment: Especially with a framework like laravel that (ab)uses multiple inheritance via traits

Comment: How can i modify this ,i need to redirect to different url's accroding to user type